# Run only When RUN AS ADMIN seleceted

Tags: powershell-2.0

i have edited script that i found ,to gather Capacity management about Network devices,and all working fine

Idea is:
for security reason i need to make the Powershell script to .exe which is no problem i made it throw Powergui and all is good,the application(.exe)  need to run on when User use  (right Click - RUN AS ADMIN) and if he just double click it ,the exe have to Give some kind of error saying the application cant run on normal Run stat

it must be run throw RUN AS ADMIN only,i thought about the UAC but this depend on machine,i need it to depend on exe only,no Group policy no UAC,any ideas? i thought about make an EXE in C+ that will run the script inside it with special environment and find the process it self to give it the permission but i failed,

i can share the script also if needed

any idea ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines will let you detect if the current user is running as an admin:

```
$currentUser = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$isAdmin = (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $currentUser).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
```

But why stop there?  I got annoyed at some of my own scripts requiring admin, and so I made a very nifty little chunk of code that will pack up a script into the background.

```
$asJobOrElevate = {
        param($CommandInfo, [switch]$OnlyCommand, [string[]]$AdditionalModules, [Hashtable]$Parameter, [Switch]$RequireAdmin)

        $currentUser = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
        $isAdmin = (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $currentUser).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)

        if ($AsJob -or $Throttle -or (-not $isAdmin) -and $requireAdmin) {           
            if ($onlyCommand) {             
                $AdditionalModules = $AdditionalModules | Select-Object -Unique
                $myDefinition = [ScriptBLock]::Create("
$(if ($AdditionalModules) {"
    Import-Module '$($AdditionalModules -join ("','"))'
"})

function $commandInfo {
   $($commandInfo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition)
 }
")                        
} else {
    $myModule = $CommandInfo.ScriptBlock.Module

    $AdditionalModules += $myModule | Split-Path
    $AdditionalModules += $myModule.RequiredModules | Split-Path
    $AdditionalModules = $AdditionalModules | Select-Object -Unique
    $myDefinition = [ScriptBLock]::Create("

$(if ($AdditionalModules) { "
    Import-Module '$($AdditionalModules -join ("','"))'
"})
")                   
 }
 $null = $Parameter.Remove('AsJob')                                    
 $null = $Parameter.Remove('Throttle')
 $null = $Parameter.Remove('RequireAdmin')                                    
 $myJob= [ScriptBLock]::Create("" + {                        
param([Hashtable]$parameter)                         

} + $myDefinition + "                        

        $commandInfo `@parameter                        
")      



          if ($Throttle) {

            $jobLaunched=  $false

            do {
                if ($myJobs) {
                    $myJobs | 
                        Receive-Job
                }


                $runningJobs = $myJobs | 
                    Where-Object { $_.State -ne 'Running' }
 if ($runningJobs) {
                    $runningJobs | 
                        Remove-Job -Force
                }



                if ($myJobs.Count -lt $throttle) {
                    $null = Start-Job -Name "${MyCmd}_Background_Job" -ScriptBlock $myJob -ArgumentList $Parameter
                    $JobLaunched = $true
                }

                $myJobs =  Get-Job -Name "${MyCmd}_Background_Job" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                Write-Progress "Waiting for Jobs to Complete" "$($myJobs.Count) Running" -Id $ProgressId  
            } until ($jobLaunched)

            $myJobs =  Get-Job -Name "${MyCmd}_Background_Job" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            $myJobs  | 
                Wait-Job | 
                Receive-Job
            return 
        } elseif ($asJob) {
            return Start-Job -ScriptBlock $myJob -ArgumentList $Parameter -Name "${CommandInfo}_Background_Job"

        } elseif ((-not $isAdmin) -and $RequireAdmin) {
                $fullCommand = "
 `$parameter = $(Write-PowerShellHashtable -InputObject $parameter)
 & { $myJob } `$parameter

 "

            $encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($fullCommand))


            return  Start-Process powershell -Verb Runas -ArgumentList '-encodedCommand', $encodedCommand -PassThru

        }
    }
    }
```

Forgive the terrible indentation.  Long code blocks are not StackOverflow's friend.  If you run that scriptblock with a line like this:

```
$launched = . $asJobOrElevate $MyInvocation.MyCommand -Parameter $psBoundParameters -RequireAdmin
```

It will launch as an admin, with a UAC prompt, if they're not one already.  It also supports running the command in a background job or throttling it to a number of running jobs.

To see this code trick in it's native habitat (or maybe just get something easier to copy/paste), check out the source of ConvertTo-ModuleService in [Powershell Pipeworks](http://powershellpipeworks.com).  It's at the top of the function, and it's the first thing in the begin {} block.

Comment: will i try to edit my hole script to work with the first line,but still it affect the way of all script working tiogether that it wont even allow to work at all

Comment: Does your script depend on other scripts?  Is it in a module?

Comment: nah,it basic script to get HDD capcity throw device on Host.txt

Comment: fixed it,added request for AD at start